# Variability of the reference data and its effect on the transformed values

Tags: data-transformation, biostatistics, median, ratio, variability

I conducted a study to compare two different tests at two different ages (children). Based on the previous literature we had hoped that the scores should be better (low score) with age but this was not true in our case.

We hypothesised that this finding could be due to the use of different tests (different tests measuring different things). To tackle this issue I collected data from a reference population using same tests  and used the median value of the reference population to calculate a ratio (divided each sample by the median of the reference population).

Now, my question is, how will the variability and spread of the reference population data affect the results that I calculated using the ratios.

Your help is much appreciated.